# Read current location name using Map View in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview, reverse-geocoding

I read the current location's latitude and longitude values and then pin that location in iPhone successfully. Now I want to read that place name using this latitude and longitude values.

I used the following code to read the find the current location:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{

    CLLocation *whereIAm = userLocation.location;

    NSLog(@"I'm at %@", whereIAm.description);

    latitude = whereIAm.coordinate.latitude;
    longitude = whereIAm.coordinate.longitude;

    NSLog(@"LAT : %f",latitude);
    NSLog(@"LONG : %f",longitude);

    mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeStandard;
    [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
    region.center.latitude =latitude;  //22.569722 ;
    region.center.longitude = longitude;  //88.369722;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 

    [mapView setDelegate:self];

    DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
    ann.title = @" Welcome";
    ann.subtitle = @"Hi"; 
    ann.coordinate = region.center; 
   [mapView addAnnotation:ann];   
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
      mapView.delegate = self;
   }



-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation: (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
   MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil; 
   if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) 
   {
    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
    pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView       dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
   }     
   [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
   return pinView;        
 }
```

Comment: You need to try to format your code again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the MKReverseGeocoderDelegate Protocol like this :

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <MKReverseGeocoderDelegate> 
{
}


@implementation YourViewController

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{
     CLLocation *whereIAm = userLocation.location;
     MKReverseGeocoder *reverseGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:whereIAm.coordinate];
     reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
     [reverseGeocoder start];
}
```

Now implement the following method delegate to get the response :

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark {
      NSLog(@"I'm at %@", placemark.locality);
}
```

For more informations look at this : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is very useful. I finished my issue for your reply. Thanks.

Comment: `MKReverseGeocoder` deprecated since iOS 5.0 you need `CLGeocoder` instead: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/index.html