# How store data when click on map?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, mkannotation, mapkit

I am making an application in which i have map view where map is zoom in. When user click on map then drop an annotation . When annotation drop on that address then that address will be store in an string. How store data in string from mapview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean the : latitute and longitude?

```
// Assume  you declare MKMapView *mapView;
CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.mapView];
CLLocationCoordinate2D locCoord =[self.mapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];

NSString *yourAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lat: %f, Lng: %f", locCoord.latitude, locCoord.longitude];
```

Hope this is what you want, if not be more specified of what you want to achieve, I will try to help.

**EDIT:**

If location is what you want, this might be of help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822297/read-current-location-name-using-map-view-in-iphone](http://read%20location)

Credits to: MathieuF who posted the sample code.

Comment: suppose u are click on map for California lactation then that location will be saved as string in our code.